# Вложенный генератор

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы, генераторы

Необходимо заменить конструкцию:

```
a = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'
for i_1 in a:
    if i_1 == 0:
        continue
    for i_2 in a:
        for i_3 in a:
            for i_4 in a:
                for i_5 in a:
                    for i_6 in a:
                        arr.append(i_1 + i_2 + i_3 + i_4 + i_5 + i_6)
```

На генератор. Как это сделать?

Comment: Для чего `if`? Он не работает. Вы хотите генерировать шестизначные числа в 36-ричной системе счисления?

Answer (score 3):

```py
import itertools

a = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz'
generator = map(''.join, itertools.product(a, repeat=6))
```

Comment: В первой позиции нужно пропускать ноль. Хотя у ТС этот код не работает как нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = (i+j+k+d+g+h for i in a for j in a for k in a for d in a for g in a for h in a)
```